# Алгоритм генерации всевозможных последовательностей

Tags: алгоритм

Вот уже второй день ломаю голову над одной "типичной программерской" задачей. Суть её заключается в том, что надо сгенирировать всевозможные числовые последовательности, сумма всех членов которых должна равняться определенному числу. Я решил эту задачу с помощью тупого перебора всевозможных последовательностей, но при больших числах время выполнения оставляет желать лучшего. Какое бы вы предложили решение?

Скажем, дана последовательность от 1 до A, пользуясь которой нужно генерировать последовательности, представляющие сумму числа N.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает что для любого числа таких последовательностей может быть сколько угодно.

5= 1 + 2 + 2 = 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 + 0.5 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = -2 + 2 - 3 + 3 + 5 = 0.2 + 4.8 = 65 - 60 и.т.д. и.т.п.

Comment: @igumnov, если рассматривать и дробные числа, и отрицательные, то да. Но я поправил свой вопрос. Спасибо!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Рекомендую почитать учебники по теории чисел. Это называется [композиции](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(number_theory)) и [разбиения](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) в зависимости от того считать ли 5=1+1+2+1+1 или 5=2+1+1+1+1 одним и тем же или нет. В Википедии более менее доходчиво изложено.

Вот скажем пример алгоритма на Java:

http://www.btinternet.com/~se16/js/PartitionChoice.java

Два примера на C++:

http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread342773.html

http://www.cyberforum.ru/cpp-beginners/thread372700.html

Вот еще хорошая бумага:

http://www.tusur.ru/filearchive/reports-magazine/2008-1/113-119.pdf

Ну и конечно классика:

[TAOCP](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/5092367/Addison_Wesley_-_2001_-_Knuth_-_The_Art_of_Computer_Programming_) том 4

7.2.1.3. Generating all combinations

7.2.1.4. Generating all partitions

Comment: Спасибо! Это будет мне полезно!

Answer (score 0):

например число 5, это 1+1+1+1+1, 2+3, 3+1+1...? правильно?
мой вариант:

1. 5/1 = 5 - последний вариант проверки
2. 5/5 = 1, те 5 раз по 1- первая последовательность
3. 5/2 = 2, 2+2+1 - 2й вариант
4. 5/3= 1+2 - 3й
    и тд. Лучше брать mod от числа и остачу делить дальше...

Надо еще додумать алгоритм.. но как то так...

Comment: Где тут алгоритм-то? И как вы таким алгоритмом получите, например `1 1 1 2` и `1 2 1 1`?

Comment: Неплохо, алгоритм явно ценен!

Comment: @Котик_хочет_кушать, сказано же, что:

     Надо еще додумать алгоритм.. но как то так...

Что собственно, не так уж и сложно =)

Comment: @Asen Да? Додумайте.